# Calculating work hours done

Tags: php, laravel, time

Hi I am making a module which calculates the user's total work of hours within a specified shift hours.

For example `$start = strtotime("15:00");` which is `3pm 2015-07-21` of the day and `$end   = strtotime("06:00");` `6am 2015-07-22`. How can I calculate their work hours based on their login and logout? I am using `Laravel 5` I made a table `loginhours` which has this structure,

```
loginhours
->id
->user_id
->loginhours
->date
->timestamp
->status
```

but hasn't made any logic how to accomplish this, those table columns might me what I need to record things or do this tasks. If you have suggestions you are free to share.  Basically, they can login and logout within shift period and just updating the `loginhours` column. So for example they login with a timestamp of `2015-07-21 03:00:00` that's `3pm` then if they logout at `4pm` they have `1.0` of login hours then they login again at `7pm` and log out at `5am of 2015-07-21` then that will be their previous login hour which is `1.0` + `10.0` because of `7pm 2015-07-20 - 5am 2015-07-21`. And should update the loginhours of that user.

I would want the checking to be on `postLogin()` and `getLogout()` of my `AuthController`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use Carbon which I think is bundled with Laravel or you can use PHP DateTime (which is what Carbon uses I think). If I am not mistaken, both of them will calculate time differences between dates.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

and

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this. I created a `work_order_sessions` so users can check in and check out of work orders and then their total hours on the work order is calculated. In your case, you could simply create a session record when a worker logs in, set start time, then when they log out, find their last (open) session and set the end time. It required some raw MySQL to calculate the hours difference for each session and then add the total hours difference per each user. Here's a snippet and link:

```
// Model WorkOrder.php

/**
 * Retrieves all of the users work order
 * sessions grouped by each user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUniqueSessions()
{
    $select = "TRUNCATE(ABS(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(work_order_sessions.in, work_order_sessions.out)) / 3600)), 2) as total_hours";

    $records = $this->sessions()
        ->select('user_id', DB::raw($select))
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->get();

    return $records;
}
```

https://github.com/stevebauman/maintenance/blob/master/src/Models/WorkOrder.php#L428

Schema:

```
    Schema::create('work_order_sessions', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('work_order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('in');
        $table->dateTime('out')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('restrict')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('work_order_id')->references('id')->on('work_orders')
            ->onUpdate('restrict')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```